# the next best easy data storage after plain text?

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm looking for a storage format for some structured data.
It's a couple of tables / 2-dim arrays.
I then want to enter the data on OS X and use it in an iOS app. It'll be a very simple learning app (for myself).
Later on I want to be able to edit the tables also on iOS.

I might want to migrate it to a database later, but for now it's most important that it's as simple as possible (since I have only very little experience with the matter).
If you can't recommend anything, I'll do it with plain text files.

But is there perhaps something simple that'll offer benefits over plain text from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use property lists (plists). They're completely native. All you need to do is stuff key-value pairs into an `NSDictionary` instance, and then invoke `-writeToFile:atomically:` or `-writeToURL:atomically:`. The dictionary will be written to disk as a plist, which you can then read back in with `[ NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: plistPath ];`

If you then want to migrate the plist to a DB, all you need to do is read in the plist from disk, and do fast enumeration over the key-value pairs, e.g.:

```
NSDictionary    *d = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: plistPath ];

for ( NSString *key in d ) {
    [ myDBObject insertValue: [ d objectForKey: key ] forKey: key ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Xml is simple and easy to understand.
Will also import later into databases's, excel and many other applications easily.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is pretty good for storing info in a simple way.

Here's a tutorial on it.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Answer (score 0):

Xml is cool but it's far from simple IMHO. json is cool, but can be tricky to be edited in a plain file. I suggest you to work on structured text, something like

```
key:value<cr>
```

an example:

```
data00: the value for entry data00
foo: the value for entry foo
bar: the value for entry bar
```

Parsing this won't be much of a burden in objective C (or in any other language), and for sure there are libraries available on the net.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the language you'r gonna use for the app
javascript: json
java: xml, csv
ruby: yaml, json, xml, csv
..
CSV and XML are generally used formats in all languages, CSV is simplest, you can find tools that work like a databasemanager for CSV and Excell works with CSV's right away. Practically all programs that handle data van export and import CSV also.

Fixed width for some purposes is also simple.
All these are essentially textfiles.

These days there are more powerfull database solutions that are also simple to setup like SQLite and some NoSql products (CouchDb, Mongo etc), you'll have more to learn though but are better on the long run.

In recent browsers you have storage possiblities.